# var inside function scss fails

Tags: scss

estoy intentando usar una variable de css dentro de la función lighten pero me da error. Alguien sabe porque? Y que podría hacer?

```
:root{
  --main-color: #F7B6F2;
  --font-color: #7E1576;
}
```

Aqui me da error:

```
input {
  color: lighten(var(--font-color),20%);
}
```

Entonces  var(--font-color) falla.
Gracias.

Comment: Traduce tu pregunta,vendrás en SO en español

Comment: Ya lo he traducido

Comment: En caso de que quieras hacerlo únicamente con CSS te recomiendo que leas este post. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45496360/using-css-variables-as-sass-function-arguments

Answer (score 1):

Por un momento pensé que tu pregunta era con respecto a hacerlo en SASS, sin embargo, en caso de que quieras cambiar de CSS a SASS te dejo la solución.

```
$font-color: #3282b8;

input {
    color: lighten($font-color, 20%);
}
```

En caso de que quieras hacerlo únicamente con CSS te recomiendo que leas este post, está en inglés, pero puede ayudarte con tu problema.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45496360/using-css-variables-as-sass-function-arguments